# Async makes render trigger before componentWillMount react?

Tags: reactjs, components, render, async.js

I've got a problem with a dropdown I want to display. My main class calls the dropdown class which then triggers, componentWillMount() which then starts the fetch but while the fetch is getting its info the render() starts and I get error because info is still null since the result hasn't been fetched yet. Anyone got any idea of how to solve this been ripping my hair with different approaches.

```
    export class Dropdown extends React.Component{
     constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            info: null   
        }
    }


     componentWillMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:8081/getUsers")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(info => {
            this.setState({info})
            console.log(info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users']);
        })

    }
    
    render(){

          const info = this.state.info;

           console.log(info);
           let menuItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'].length; i++) {
        menuItems.push(<MenuItem eventKey="[i]">info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users']['mta:FullName'][i]</MenuItem>);
    }

     return (
    <DropdownButton bsStyle="primary" title="Users" key="dropdown1" id="1">
      <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
      {menuItems}
    </DropdownButton>
  );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just render null until the data has been properly fetched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check the value of info and return null if its null and then when the state updates it will return the DropDown

Example

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.info) return null;
  const info = this.state.info;
  console.log(info);
  let menuItems = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'].length; i++) {
    menuItems.push(<MenuItem eventKey="[i]">info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users']['mta:FullName'][i]</MenuItem>);
  }
  return (
    <DropdownButton bsStyle="primary" title="Users" key="dropdown1" id="1">
      <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
      {menuItems}
    </DropdownButton>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it user friendly, you can show `loading...` text or animated icon instead of drop-down:

```
render() {
  const { info } = this.state.info;
  if (!info) return(
     <div className="loader">Loading...</div>
  )

  // the code below will execute when `info` is not null.
  let menuItems = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'].length; i++) {
    menuItems.push(<MenuItem eventKey={i}>{info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'][i]['mta:FullName']}</MenuItem>);
  }
  return (
    <DropdownButton bsStyle="primary" title="Users" key="dropdown1" id="1">
      <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
      {menuItems}
    </DropdownButton>
  );
}
```

But I think it would be nicer to render `DropdownButton` unconditionally and populate option on success response:

```
render() {
  let MenuItems = []
  const { info } = this.state.info

  if (!info) {
    MenuItems.push(<MenuItem>Loading...</MenuItem>)
  }
  else {
    info['mta:getUsersResponse']['mta:users'].forEach((elem, i) => {
      MenuItems.push(<MenuItem eventKey={i}>{elem['mta:FullName']}</MenuItem>)
    })
  }

  return (
    <DropdownButton bsStyle="primary" title="Users" key="dropdown1" id="1">
      {menuItems}
    </DropdownButton>
  )
}
```